# Autocontrolling of many tunnels

Tags: ssh, tunnel

During my work I need to set up many tunnels. What is the best practice to manage it? Sometime tunnels can lost connection I want to auto reconnect it, maybe there is good thing to do it automatically

Comment: You could try to write a bash script that does what you want, I don't work with tunnels so I cant help you sadly, but take a look around! :)

Comment: I take it its a SSH tunnel? or VPN?

Comment: Just simple ssh -D 7070 user@example.net

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Stack exchange! give it a shot!

```
#!/bin/sh

REMOTEUSER=username
REMOTEHOST=remotehost 

SSH_REMOTEPORT=22 
SSH_LOCALPORT=10022

TUNNEL_REMOTEPORT=8080
TUNNEL_LOCALPORT=8080

createTunnel() {
    /usr/bin/ssh -f -N  -L$SSH_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:SSH_REMOTEPORT -L$TUNNEL_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:TUNNEL_REMOTEPORT $REMOTEUSER@$REMOTEHOST
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo Tunnel to $REMOTEHOST created successfully
    else
        echo An error occurred creating a tunnel to $REMOTEHOST RC was $?
    fi
}

## Run the 'ls' command remotely.  If it returns non-zero, then create a new connection
/usr/bin/ssh -p $SSH_LOCALPORT $REMOTEUSER@localhost ls >/dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo Creating new tunnel connection
    createTunnel
fi
```

This script will open two ports, ports 22 which will be used to check if the tunnel is still alive
and port 8080 which is the port you might want to use (you can change that ofcourse)

Comment: do note that this is for one ssh, you can probably copy and paste it a few times for different tunnels